# Form without a border style

Tags: c#

I've stumbled upon a problem. I'm using 'FormBorderStyle.None', and when I click the icon of my running application on the taskbar it does not minimize like it should, although when I use anything BUT 'FormBorderStyle.None', it seems to work perfectly. Please advice me of a good way to tackle this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must override CreateParams:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            CreateParams par = base.CreateParams;
            par.Style = par.Style | 0x20000; // Turn on the WS_MINIMIZEBOX style flag
            return par;
        }
    }
}
```

Check [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/6b91ed64-bc6e-43b6-a869-819f5d0e8fc6/) for an explanation.